# How much files can be sended via python using tftp

Tags: python, telnet, tftp

I have python script: Using telnet it connects to remote host via telnet and simply executing command. It works fine with one host, but If i want using function to connect to 4+ hosts it maybe from 4-5 try sends only one random.

```
def main():
     usr = "adm"
     ip = "192.168.5.15"
     pwd = "123456"
     command = "tftp ......" (works fine)

     com(ip,usr,pwd,command)

def com(host,usr,pwd,comm):
    HOST=host
    user=usr
    password=pwd
    command = comm

    try:
     telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
     telnet.read_until(b"Username:")
     telnet.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

     same for password

     telnet.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
     telnet.close()
     except:
       pass
main()
```

Are there any limits for telnet connections in python or something that can limit number of sending files or anything?

Comment: I'd start by not masking all exceptions to see what is going on as if something did not get sent, I would presume it failed and included some indication as to why. Could you, please, do that or at least print the exception(s) and backtrace(s) and add that to your question?

Comment: If you are about telnet debugging it returns that it sends coommand on remote host